# Error: Expected "/* Begin ", "/* End ", "\"", or [A-Za-z0-9_.] but "/" found

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I got this error after I add iOS to my cordova project. 
By using following command,

```
sudo cordova platform add ios
```

I cleared xcode DerivedData and also re-install by following command

```
sudo cordova platform rm ios
sudo cordova platform add ios
```

and there is still no luck.

I found other suggestion that need to look for conflict in `my-app.xcodeproj` > `project.pbxproj` and it does not have conflict.

Any other solution to solve above problems?
thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve the problem by following.

Firstly, enter the following to clean iOS platform in my cordova project.

`./platforms/ios/cordova/clean`

From the output, I was able to see which line number got unexpected character but it never tells which file got problem. So I look for line number 70 (for my case is line number 70) in `my-app.xcodeproj` > `project.pbxproj`. So, I comment out the line and try clean again, and the error was gone.